# Failed in getting the Value from textbox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a page where it gets all the employee details from database and shows the data in textboxes it should be edited after I change the details of employee

my problems is it is not getting the value from the textbox to update

this is my textbox aspx code

```
<div class="col-md-3"> First Name
                            <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="entypo-user"></i></span>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

and this is the code for getting the textbox value:

```
protected void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            empenty.FirstName = fname.Text;
            empenty.LastName = txtlaname.Text;
            empenty.Gender = ddlselect.SelectedItem.Text;
            empenty.DateOfBirth = txtdob.Text;
            empenty.MobileNumber = txtmnumber.Text;
            empenty.AlternateNumber = txtanumber.Text;
            empenty.EmailId = txtemail.Text;
            empenty.AlternateEmail = txtaemail.Text;
            empenty.FatherName = txtfaname.Text;
            empenty.MotherName = txtmoname.Text;
            empenty.AadhaarCardNo = txtacno.Text;
            empenty.PanCardNo = txtpcno.Text;
            empenty.PassportNo = txtpassno.Text;
            empenty.UserName = txtuname.Text;
            empenty.Password = txtpwd.Text;
            empenty.RAddressLine1 = txtraline1.Text;
            empenty.RAddressLine2 = txtraline2.Text;
            empenty.RCity = txtrcity.Text;
            empenty.RState = txtrstate.Text;
            empenty.RZipCode = txtrzcode.Text;
            empenty.RCountry = txtrcountry.Text;
            empenty.PAddressLine1 = txtraline1.Text;
            empenty.PAddressLine2 = txtpaline2.Text;
            empenty.PCity = txtpcity.Text;
            empenty.PState = txtpstate.Text;
            empenty.PZipCode = txtpzcode.Text;
            empenty.PCountry = txtpcountry.Text;
            empenty.OAddressLine1 = txtoaline1.Text;
            empenty.OAddressLine2 = txtoaline2.Text;
            empenty.OCity = txtocity.Text;
            empenty.OState = txtostate.Text;
            empenty.OZipCode = txtozcode.Text;
            empenty.OCountry = txtocountry.Text;
            int update = bal.empudate(empenty, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["empid"].ToString()));

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert(' Successfully updated!');window.location.href = 'Newemployee.aspx'", true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I have tried putting breakpoints and check the code when I hover the mouse over the `fname.Text` it is showing the previous value which is stored while getting the data from database.

likewise it is not getting the new value from textboxes it is showing the previous value for every textbox.

This is my page_load code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Get_emp_data_to_update();
        GetEmpSeq();

    }
```

This is code for Get_emp_data_to_update():

```
private void Get_emp_data_to_update()
    {
        ViewState["empid"] = empid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["empid"].ToString());

        using (dtst = bal.Getempedit(empid))
        {
            fname.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["firstname"].ToString();
            txtlaname.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Lastname"].ToString();
            ddlselect.SelectedValue = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Gender"].ToString();
            txtdob.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DateofBirthday"].ToString();
            txtmnumber.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Mobilenumber"].ToString();
            txtanumber.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Alternatenumber"].ToString();
            txtemail.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Emailid"].ToString();
            txtaemail.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AlternateEmail"].ToString();
            txtfaname.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Fathername"].ToString();
            txtmoname.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Mothername"].ToString();
            txtacno.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AadhaarCardNo"].ToString();
            txtpcno.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PanCardNo"].ToString();
            txtpassno.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PassportNo"].ToString();
            txtuname.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
            txtpwd.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
            txtraline1.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RAddressLine1"].ToString();
            txtraline2.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RAddressLine2"].ToString();
            txtrcity.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RCity"].ToString();
            txtrstate.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RState"].ToString();
            txtrzcode.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RZipCode"].ToString();
            txtrcountry.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["RCountry"].ToString();
            txtpaline1.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PAddressLine1"].ToString();
            txtpaline2.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PAddressLine2"].ToString();
            txtpcity.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PCity"].ToString();
            txtpstate.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PState"].ToString();
            txtpzcode.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PZipCode"].ToString();
            txtpcountry.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PCountry"].ToString();
            txtoaline1.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OAddressLine1"].ToString();
            txtoaline2.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OAddressLine2"].ToString();
            txtocity.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OCity"].ToString();
            txtostate.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OState"].ToString();
            txtozcode.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OZipCode"].ToString();
            txtocountry.Text = dtst.Tables[0].Rows[0]["OCountry"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post your `Page_Load` event handier code

Comment: @CoolBots I have added the code pls review it

Comment: add if(!IsPostBack) condition on Page_Load.

Comment: Is `GetEmpSeq();` the function that loads the data from the database?

Comment: @CoolBots Error has been resolved thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check IsPostBack in page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        Get_emp_data_to_update();
        GetEmpSeq();

     }
}
```